# Value of integral function

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $G$ an antiderivative of function $g(x)=\frac{e^x}{e^x+e^2x+1}$ such that $G(1)=0$. I have to compute $G(0)$.
I tried and i defined $G(x):=\int_{1}^x \frac{e^t}{e^t+e^2t+1}dt$, so that $G(1)=0$. Now from fundamental theorem of calculus I have:$\int_{1}^0\frac{e^t}{e^t+e^2t+1}dt=G(0)-G(1)$.

But, I can't compute the LHS...how could i continue?

Comment: Are you sure this is the question because this question feels like we should have $\frac{e^t}{2e^t+{e^2t}+1}$ or $\frac{e^t}{e^t+e^{2t}+1}$ instead of $\frac{e^t}{e^t+e^2t+1}$. But if it isn't then just by writing "integrate e^x/(e^x+e^2*x+1) from 0 to 1" to wolframalpha solves the question.

Comment: The question is with $e^x+e^2x+1$ and i don't search a numerical method. I wondered if there was a way a bit more "analytic".

Comment: $e^{2x}+e^x+1 = (e^x + \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4}$, now substitute $t = e^x + \frac{1}{2} \implies e^x dx = dt$. So all you need to do is integrate $\int \frac{dt}{t^2 + \frac{3}{4}}$ which is standard form

Comment: I don't have $e^{2x}+e^x+1$, but $e^x+e^2*x+1$!

Comment: Be sure that there is a typo ! It cannot be $e^x+e^2x+1$